# multiple show and hide post on jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hide, show

I'd like to optimize this script on **multiple** div's. 
Now is working, but for single div.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".hideDiv").hide();
    $(".buttonshow").show();

    $('.buttonshow').click(function(){
    $(".hideDiv").slideToggle();
     $(".buttonshow").hide();
    });

    $('.buttonhide').click(function(){
    $(".hideDiv").slideToggle();
    $(".buttonshow").show();
    });

});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qya3xp76/7/)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $(".hideDiv").hide();
     $('.buttonshow').click(function () {
         $(this).next(".hideDiv").slideToggle();
         $(".buttonshow").hide();
     });
     $('.buttonhide').click(function () {
         $(this).parent().slideToggle();
         $(".buttonshow").show();
     });
 });
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/qya3xp76/12/)**

Comment: 1) .buttonshow dont hide if we click 2) .buttonhiden dont hide this div

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: is posible to hide one .buttonshow (this clicked) not all .buttonshow?

Comment: So if you click button 2, hide button 2 and keep buttons 1 and 3 visible?

Comment: yes.click button 2, hide button 2 and keep buttons 1 and 3 visible

Comment: no, if i click on "Show DIV2" keep buttons 1 and 3 visible.

Answer (score 0):

**JQuery:**

```
$(".hideDiv, .buttonshow").toggle(); 

    $('.buttonshow').click(function(){
        $(".hideDiv, .buttonshow").slideToggle();
    });

    $('.buttonhide').click(function(){
        $(".hideDiv, .buttonshow").slideToggle();
});
```

**CSS:**

> .hideDiv{
>       display: block; } .buttonshow {
>       display: none; }

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mrvijayakumar/qya3xp76/17/)**